# NPAPI and GOOGLE Chrome : MIME type of DLL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi

What is MIME type of DLL that required to to set in following tag.

```
<embed id="pluginId" type="application/<MIME TYPE OF DLL>"
```

Do I need to make changes in DLL to set MIME type of DLL? 
I have read on forum, to set mime type in .rc file.
VALUE "MIMEType", "application/myapp"

But how to do with vs 2008 DLL.

Comment: Also just an FYI, I have had much more consistant results with an object tag rather than an embed tag and highly recommend you use object and not embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the mimetype is set in the .rc file, which requires a recompile. To se the mimetype, put it in a STRING resource called MIMEType.

see https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/gen_templates/firebreathWin.rc#L63 -- this is FireBreath's .rc file template.

Comment: I have created DLL.
DLL is getting loaded in google chrome browser but Unable to call
function of dll through JavaScript.

<embed type="application/NPAPIDLL" id="pluginId">
var plugin = document.getElementById("pluginId");
var result = plugin.myPluginMethod();  // Exported function from DLL
which has to called from JavaScript

Do I need to provide function pointer for myPluginMethod in any of
these function:
  NP_GetEntryPoints
  NP_Initialize
  NP_Shutdown
  NPP_New

In order to get called from JavaScript.

Comment: That would be better as a new question, but you need to provide a NPObject. See http://npapi.com/tutorial3